# What to choose for a writing sample?

Tags: phd, united-states, application, writing

I am applying to a PhD program in the US (nutritional sciences), and they require me to submit a writing sample, but as I'm from Spain all of my previous work is in Spanish. I have thought about translating and submitting my Master's Thesis , but there is a 10 page limit. I don't know if you recommend submitting one section and which one should I choose (abstract, introduction, results and discussion, more than one section...) or summarize the thesis in 10 pages. I feel like the results and discussion would be the best option but it uses a lot of terminology that it's impossible to understand without Materials and Methods section.

Also, should I include the bibliography if there are references in the text and do they count for the page limit (the program's webpage doesn't specify this)?

Answer (score 2):

Since they likely want an English language text, a translation probably isn't appropriate. But they don't need a complete work.

One option is to write a summary of your masters thesis in English. Perhaps something you might prepare if you had to give a lecture on the subject to an English speaking audience.